# Keep button from moving down when popup shows

Tags: html, css

I'm working with code that's way too long to show, but basically, I have a popup like in the image that is moving my button down. **EDIT: I want the button right underneath input box only and popup to stay to the side**  So I recreated some of it in CodeSandbox as shown in the image. I have seen this question before but the implementations haven't worked for me and I can't figure this out.

[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/cbradio_nyc/pen/gOKOYPo)

```css
.js-input {
  background: green;
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
}

.js-popup {
  background: blue;
  width: 80px;
  height: 120px;
  position: absolute
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container d-flex g6">
  <div class="js-input">Input</div>
  <div class="js-popup">Popup</div>
</div>

<div class=" button">
  <button class="s-btn s-btn__primary">Button</button>
</div>
```

I've tried making the top div position relative and the button absolute. I got it to work a bit if I make the popup position absolute also but then it's shifted all the way to the left. So then I tried to keep the code that way and shift the popup to the right with justify-content, etc.

Comment: Share your pen or your actual code instead of its image.

Comment: the info you provided is not enough. do you want the button under the input and then the popup under them or what? I think you should make the popup absolute.